# How to pass a variable from twig to vueJS (symfony 2.8 and VueJS 2)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, vue.js, twig

I have a symfony 2.8 application and I recently integrated VueJs 2 as my front-end framework, because it gives a lot of flexibility.
My application is not single page and I use the symfony controllers to render views. All the views are wrapped in a base twig layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app.request.locale|split('_')[0] }}">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="/js/fos_js_routes.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/vendor-bundle.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/vue-bundle.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I load most of the JS with webpack, all my vue components and JS dependencies are compiled in `vendor-bundle.js` and `vue-bundle.js`. My VueJs instance looks like this:

```
import './components-dir/component.vue'
import './components-dir/component2.vue'

Vue.component('component', Component);
Vue.component('component2', Component2);

window.onload = function () {
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {}
    });
};
```

I want to pass some php variables from the controller to the vuejs componets, but I can't manage to make it work.

A very simple example of a controller looks like this:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/contract", name="contract")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $paymentMethods = PaymentMethod::getChoices();

        return $this->render('contracts/index.html.twig', [
            'paymentMethods'   => $serializer->normalize($paymentMethods, 'json'),
        ]);
    }
```

All the html, css and js are handled by vueJs. The twig view looks like this:

```
{% extends 'vue-base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <contracts :paymentMethods="{{paymentMethods | raw}}"></contracts>
{% endblock %}
```

The `contracts.vue` component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Hi from component</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        props: ['paymentMethods'],
        mounted: function () {
            console.log(this.paymentMethods)
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

> How can I pass the php variables as props to vueJs ?

In the example above, I don't get any errors, but the property is not passed to vuejs. The console log prints `undefined`.
I want to be able to do this, because I don't want to have a SPA, but I also want to pass some variables from symfony to vue, because I won't have to make additional requests.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing Twig variable as value of Vue attr:

```
<contracts :payment-methods="{{ twigVar}}"></contracts>
```

you can render whole using twig:

```
<contracts {{ ':payment-methods="' ~ twigVar ~ '"' }}></contracts>
```

Thanks to this you will avoid delimeters  conflict between vue and twig.

Also as the value comes directly from twig, it probably wont change upon a time, as it is generated in backend - not in some vue-source - so you don't need to bind it, just pass it like:

```
<contracts payment-methods="{{ twigVar}}"></contracts>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the following to your .vue file   `props: ['paymentMethods']` please refer to the following url for complete documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten to write that in my .vue file I have the `props` property already defined. I've updated my question.

Comment: do you have the vue DevTools installed? if so go to the root and check what paymentMethods shows.  @StefanGramadnikov

Comment: whoops remove the `:` from `:paymentMethods` it shoud be just `paymentMethods`

Comment: Tried it both ways, the difference is that with `:` the property is dynamic, but in my case it doesn't matter.

Comment: well when you use the : itll think its a vue variable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to pass variables from twig to Vue application is:

Twig:

```
<div id="app" data-foo="{{ foo }}" data-bar="{{ bar }}"></div>
```

JS:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: '',
    bar: ''
  },
  template: '<div>foo = {{ foo }}</div><div>bar = {{ bar }}</div>',
  beforeMount: function() {
    this.foo = this.$el.attributes['data-foo'].value
    this.bar = this.$el.attributes['data-bar'].value
  }
})
```

If you would like to use a Vue component you can do it the following way:

Twig:

```
<div id="app" data-foo="{{ foo }}" data-bar="{{ bar }}"></div>
```

JS:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from 'App'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render(h) {
    return h(App, {
      props: {
        foo: this.$el.attributes['data-foo'].value,
        bar: this.$el.attributes['data-bar'].value,
      }
    })
  }
})
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>foo = {{ foo }}</div>
  <div>bar = {{ bar }}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['foo', 'bar'],
  }
</script>
```

Please note if you would like to pass arrays you should convert them to json format before:

Twig:

```
<div id="app" data-foo="{{ foo|json_encode }}"></div>
```

and then you should decode json:

JS:

```
this.foo = JSON.parse(this.$el.attributes['data-foo'].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to the party, but if anyone is having the same issue, the problem here was the casing.

CamelCased props like `paymentMethods` are converted to hyphen-case in html, and can be used like this:

```
<contracts :payment-methods="{{ paymentMethods | raw }}"></contracts>
```